# Desktop freezes regularly. Ctrl+Alt+F keys doesn't work

Tags: 14.04, xorg, freeze

I've been running 14.04 on my work computer (Dell Latitude E6440) since last May with no issues. 4 or 5 weeks ago I upgraded to the 3.16 kernel and the newer X.org via the LTS Enablement Stack. Everything went smoothly until about a week ago when I started getting random screen freezes. A few times a day my desktop will freeze. When this happens, I can still move the mouse pointer but not between screens (I use the built-in display with 2 external ones). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> keys don't do anything. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> (I've enabled that) seems to work sometimes but takes a really long time to restart the display server.

I've been looking at the X log, but nothing is popping out as particularly useful. How can I diagnose what's causing this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I recommend people do when their computer starts to freeze up randomly is check harddrive health. Probably the easiest way to do this within Ubuntu (or another Linux environment), is via [GSmartControl](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gsmartcontrol/), which I personally use as a technician to check hard drive health through Parted Magic. If it's not your hard drive it might still be some form of hardware issue (I've had systems act this way due to dieing graphics cards), or it might be something your recently configured/installed that's interfering with a system process.